# Translation Interface for Flask Babel

Tags: python, flask, translation, flask-babel

Good evening,

I'm developing an Python API app with Flask Framework and I used Flask Babel to translate content. It works with .po and .mo files.

theme.po - this is a ASCII file (readable text). It's responsible for most of the text displayed on the website. This is the file that will be edited.

theme.mo - this is a binary file (machine readable). This is the actual file used by Osclass and is compiled from the .po file.

Is there anything like transifex that I can use? What translation interface/tool do you advise to make the website translation more friendly to a non specialized end user?

Regards

Answer (score -1):

There is [poedit](https://poedit.net/download) (advised somewhere in the flask or babel doc)